# not enough arguments for format string

Tags: python, psycopg2

Im trying to pass a sql ( wich works perfectly if i run it on the client ) inside my python script, but  i receive the error "not enough arguments for format string"

Following, the code:

```
sql = """
SELECT
  rr.iserver,
    foo.*, rr.queue_capacity,
    rr.queue_refill_level,
    rr.is_concurrent,
    rr.max_execution_threads,
    rr.retrieval_status,
    rr.processing_status
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            ip.package,
            it. TRIGGER
        FROM
            wip.info_package ip,
            wip.info_trigger it
        WHERE
            ip.service = it.service and
      ip.iserver = '%(iserver)s' and
      it.iserver = %(iserver)s'
        AND package = '%(package)s'
        UNION
            SELECT
                '%(package)s' AS package,
                TRIGGER
            FROM
                info_trigger
            WHERE
                TRIGGER LIKE '%(package)s%'
    ) AS foo,
    info_trigger rr
WHERE
    rr. TRIGGER = foo. TRIGGER
""" % {'iserver' : var_iserver,'package' : var_package}
dcon = Database_connection()
getResults = dcon.db_call(sql, dbHost, dbName, dbUser, dbPass)
# more and more code to work the result....
```

My main problem on this is how i can pass `'%(iserver)s' , '%(package)s'`  correctly. Because usualy, when i select's or insert's on database, i only use two variables , but i dont know how to do it with more than two.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
WHERE
                TRIGGER LIKE '%(package)s%'
```

you have an EXTRA '%'

if you want the actual character '%', you need to escape with a double '%'.

so it should be

```
WHERE
                TRIGGER LIKE '%(package)s%%'
```

if you want to display a '%'

and

```
WHERE
                TRIGGER LIKE '%(package)s'
```

if you dont

Comment: You may also want to switch to using [str.format()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), as it's preferred over % in Python 3

Comment: @ernie thanks +1, i did not know that. i wonder if its cosmetic, or if there are some real reasons for this.

Answer (score 9):

Don't build SQL like this using `%`:

```
"SELECT %(foo)s FROM bar WHERE %(baz)s" %
  {"foo": "FOO", "baz": "1=1;-- DROP TABLE bar;"}
```

This opens the door for nasty SQL injection attacks.

Use the proper form of your [Python Database API Specification v2.0](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) adapter. For Psychopg this form is described [here](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries).

```
cur.execute("SELECT %(foo)s FROM bar WHERE %(baz)s",
  {"foo": "FOO", "baz": "1=1;-- DROP TABLE bar;"})
```